# Kotlin not compiling lambdas in android library

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kotlin, lambda

I have an android library which I'm calling from within Unity (but that shouldn't be important). I have this code:

```
class UnityInterop {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun initialize() = initInternal()

        private fun initInternal(): Boolean {
            executePluginFunction {
                // do some stuff here...
            }

            return false
        }

        fun executePluginFunction(func: () -> Unit) {
            try {
                UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread {
                    func()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this error, which looks like it's saying that the class generated for the lambda isn't there:

```
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/onehand/nativekeyboard/UnityInterop$Companion$initInternal$1;
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.onehand.nativekeyboard.UnityInterop$Companion.initInternal(UnityInterop.kt:87)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.onehand.nativekeyboard.UnityInterop$Companion.initialize(UnityInterop.kt:81)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.onehand.nativekeyboard.UnityInterop.initialize(Unknown Source:2)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:88)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   :      at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
06-04 20:07:09.767  5469  5493 E Unity   : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.onehand.nativekeyboard.UnityInterop$Companion$initInternal$1
```

So I decompiled the jar from inside the aar, and as far as jd-gui can tell me, the lambda really isn't there. What's happening here? Here are the gradle scripts, just in case:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

---

EDIT: I was looking in the wrong place. The classes are all there inside the jar. I still don't know why they're not being loaded though. And jd-gui *did* fail to show any source for the class Android thinks is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. The real error was being reported when the apk was installed, saying that my lambda's class could not be resolved due to a missing class from kotlin's base libraries. To solve it, I had to include the correct version of `kotlin-stdlib` (1.3.11 in my case) in the build. To do that, I used [Google JAR resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) with this `Dependencies.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <androidPackages>
    <androidPackage spec="org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11" />
  </androidPackages>
</dependencies>
```